# Cant install DDevextensions 1.6 on Delphi 7 and windows 10

Tags: delphi, windows-10, delphi-7

some years ago I installed  DDevextensions 1.6 so that I could search my componenents.  Worked a treat.  Had a recent crash and re-installed everything but now cannot install ddevextensions - I run the exe file (as administrator) and it comes up with a window which is headed 'Install in/uninstall', showing a blank list box into which I cannot enter anything and with 2 greyed out buttons (install and uninstall) plus 'Quit'.  Parameters dont seem to work so I am stuck.  Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: D7 on W10 not good idea. try to run D7 in VM with guest OS: XP (VMWare Player; Oracle VirtualBox)

Comment: The installer reads your Delphi installation info from the registry and populates the list box. If the list box is empty, it's not finding your Delphi installation. Did you run the Delphi installer as administrator as well? D7 is very old, and writes to both HKLM and the Program Files and Windows system folders.

Comment: @Zam:  For the most part, D7 out-of-the-box runs fine on Win10, better than, f.i. some of MS's own flagship products, e.g. Sql Server 2k which won't even install on Win10.  Do you have a reproducible counter-example?  If so, please share.

Answer (score 0):

Use DDevExtensions 2.4 for Delphi 7. Works fine for me (Delphi 7 on Win 10)

Comment: This does not answer the question asked, which  is how to install v1.6. It's a comment to the original question instead, which you will be able to post once you've earned the comment privilege. It's improper to use the answer space to bypass not having that privilege.